# How to set inline style in Pug using database values

Tags: mongoose, pug

I am trying to apply a style conditionally to an element in pug using my database values, but it isn't working as expected, and I don't know how to fix it.

```
.promo-bar-section.w-clearfix(style='background-color: #{data[0].bgcolor};', data-ix='promo-bar-section-hide')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
.promo-bar-section.w-clearfix(style='background-color:' + data[0].bgcolor + ';', data-ix='promo-bar-section-hide')
```